# CSS3-PIE: ie 8 weird black spot issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

If you have a look at the following link: `http://78.109.168.22/tv` - you will notice that in IE8 in the middle of the logo header there is a little black spotted area. I have no idea what it could be!

Has anyone got any ideas? I would love to hear them! It's driving me crazy.

Screenshot of what I'm talking about - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTOTi.png

Solution was a Drupal skip link ID. I just displayed this id to none in IE8 and it has now be resolved. Thank you all!

Comment: Post the erroneous code to make your question valid for future as well.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong... (IE9 with document mode set as IE8)

Comment: Added screenshot to show what I mean

Comment: @ejay I would if I knew what the erroneous code was, once I figure it out I will post it in my original post

Comment: I don't see anything on your screenshot...

Comment: you mean the little black rectangular area in top-middle of the header?

Comment: @Ejay... that is not present in FF?

Comment: @ejay Yes that's the culprit!

Comment: I'm not getting that rectangle in any IE version

Comment: It's only in IE8 and lower.

Comment: Can't be reproduced in IE8. I think that's because of that "select <PDF ICON>" toolbar you are running?

Comment: Just disabled that PDF icon bar, still there. I'm running IE9 set to IE8 mode

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this in IE10 with IE8 doc mode. However, something on page hang my IE, so I can't debug anything.

Comment: it has to do something with CSS3 PIE solution you're using. Specifically `js/PIE.htc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These line of code creating the problem

```
<div id="skip-link">
        <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: You've just made a statement, not an answer

Comment: His statement has answered my question. Thank you very much mani!

Comment: To me it seems as though what your seeing is an alternative header/menu for mobile devices for users who are browsing the website on a mobile device.

The complete image looks like the image below.
And the Black BAR is probably a drag handle to slide  the menu up or down as required.

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aBNQz.jpg

Comment: problem is because of

.element-invisible {
position: absolute !important;
clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
overflow: hidden;
height: 1px;}

ie ignore 1px height add font-size:1px also may solve your problem.
try not sure